# spark streaming - create tmp view in one stream and use in in another

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run 2 Dstreams, generate Dataframe in the first one register the df as tmp view and then use it in another Dstream as follows:

```
dstream1.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  import org.apache.spark.sql._
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate
  import spark.implicits._
  import spark.sql

  val records = rdd.toDF("record")
  records.createOrReplaceTempView("records")
}
dstream2.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  import org.apache.spark.sql._
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate
  import spark.implicits._
  import spark.sql

  val records2 = rdd.toDF("record2")
  val oldRecord = spark.table("records")
  records2.join(oldRecod).write.json(...)
}
streamingContext.remember(Seconds(60))
    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

I'm keep getting an `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException` 
so obviously I'm not doing something right.

is there a way to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this actually worked,
the problem was that when tested locally you need to leave extra core for calculation other then bringing the data from the stream.

I used master = local[2] thus each core is used to process each stream and non left to do anything else.
once I changed it to master = local[4] it worked fine